# Deserialize_keras_object 'module' object is not callable

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, typeerror

I am trying to start the training of a NN but when I invoke the script, the following traceback occurs. The type error occurs when the name of the module I import is the same then function I am using, I understand that but I have no clue which function or module is the problem here, since it traces to a keras module.

Can someone please help me out here?

Thanks!

```
  File "/path/to/train_demo.py", line 83, in <module>
    main()
  File "/path/to/train_demo.py", line 25, in main
    model = load_model(
  File "/path/to/anaconda3/envs/tf-gpu/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/save.py", line 206, in load_model
    return hdf5_format.load_model_from_hdf5(filepath, custom_objects,
  File "/path/to/anaconda3/envs/tf-gpu/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/hdf5_format.py", line 183, in load_model_from_hdf5
    model = model_config_lib.model_from_config(model_config,
  File "/path/to/anaconda3/envs/tf-gpu/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/model_config.py", line 64, in model_from_config
    return deserialize(config, custom_objects=custom_objects)
  File "/path/to/anaconda3/envs/tf-gpu/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/serialization.py", line 173, in deserialize
    return generic_utils.deserialize_keras_object(
  File "/path/to/anaconda3/envs/tf-gpu/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/generic_utils.py", line 365, in deserialize_keras_object
    return cls.from_config(
  File "/path/to/anaconda3/envs/tf-gpu/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 2261, in from_config
    return functional.Functional.from_config(
  File "/path/to/anaconda3/envs/tf-gpu/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/functional.py", line 668, in from_config
    input_tensors, output_tensors, created_layers = reconstruct_from_config(
  File "/path/to/anaconda3/envs/tf-gpu/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/functional.py", line 1275, in reconstruct_from_config
    process_layer(layer_data)
  File "/path/to/anaconda3/envs/tf-gpu/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/functional.py", line 1257, in process_layer
    layer = deserialize_layer(layer_data, custom_objects=custom_objects)
  File "/path/to/anaconda3/envs/tf-gpu/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/serialization.py", line 173, in deserialize
    return generic_utils.deserialize_keras_object(
  File "/path/to/anaconda3/envs/tf-gpu/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/generic_utils.py", line 380, in deserialize_keras_object
    return cls(**cls_config)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Comment: Can you share standalone code to replicate your issue? so that we can try to help you. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Tfer2, I already found a workaround, thanks for replying!

Comment: ,That's good to hear. For the benefit of community please post solution in answer section. Thanks!